# How to define controllers in multiple files - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to define controllers in separate files, but I'm getting the error:

```
transactionsController not a function got undefined
```

**File structure**

I have added files in this sequence
1- common.js
2- transactions.js

**Common.js**
In common files I have defined

```
var app = angular.module("spModule", ["ngMessages", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

**Transactions.js**

```
angular.module('spModule').controller('transactionsController',
    ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {} ]
);
```

**HTML FIle**

```
<body ng-app="spModule" ng-controller="transactionsController">
```

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure you're loading the files in the correct order?
The error looks strange? Is that really the error you got?

Comment: did you include the Transactions.js file in the HTML document?

Comment: i've noticed the errors from angular coming back slightly strange. This seems to definitely be a script include/ordering problem, post the entire HTML. There is also no point in specifying an `app` variable if you don't use it in that file either.

Comment: try $compile, or plunker

Comment: @AndreasArgelius not getting  any error regarding file includes ,

Comment: @AndrewCounts no its php file somelike header.php

Comment: @AliRaza I highly suggest you post more information with your question, it is impossible to give you an answer at this point. Otherwise this question will have to be flagged

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First, you should get rid of the global `app` variable. This is not necessary. Second, you have to understand the principle of the `angular.module()` method.

Using `angular.module()` with two parameters (e.g. `angular.module('my-module', [])`) would result in **setting** a new module with its corresponding dependencies. In contrast, when using `angular.module('my-module')` the corresponding module is looked up internally and returned to the caller (**getting**).

The means when you first define you application you might just create the following files and structure.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**FirstController.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstController', function () {});
```

**SecondController.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondController', function () {});
```

If you now include these files in your html document in this particularly order (at least **app.js** has to come first), your application works just fine with two separate controllers in two separate files.

#### Further readings

I can recommend the [AngularJS Styleguide on modules](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#modules) for getting more ideas on this topic.

Comment: yes, it works!!!.  Be sure the first time you write .module(one argument, second argument), Others controllers, .module(just one argument) . The first time, it creates an instance, and the other ones, it gets the instance!!

Answer (score 3):

You Can put this controller in seprate file like mycontroller1.js

```
    

    app.controller('myController', ['$scope',function($scope)    
        {
        $scope.myValue='hello World'
        }])
```

Same like  this you can create new js file 'myNewcontroller.js' and can put new controller :

```
    app.controller('myController2', ['$scope',function($scope)    
        {
        $scope.myValue='hello World'
        }])
```

Hope this will help you :) Cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this stuff by creating modules. Create module and respective controllers. And inject that module to the main app module.

```
Transactions.js

(function() {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('tmodule', []);
})();

(function() {
   'use strict';
    angular.module('tmodule').controller('transactionsController', ['$scope', '$http', 
            function ($scope, $http){
    }]);

})();
```

Now inject the "tmodule" to your Common.js file-

```
  var app = angular.module("spModule", ["ngMessages", "ui.bootstrap","tmodule"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Load your common.js first. Move ng-app directive to `<html>` tag. Change transaction.js to:

```
app.controller('transactionsController', TransactionsController)

TransactionsController.$inject = ['$scope','$http']

function TransactionsController($scope, $http) {


};
```

Just for fun. Let me know what happens.