# Including Angular controllers on separate page

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on converting an existing patchwork app into an Angular app. The app is built on a CMS that bundles "components" together as packages that are reusable throughout the site, so the most effective solution right now is to bundle the relevant JS to a unique component as an inline `<script>` tag and leaving global functionality in a separate JS file that every page on the site shares. The CMS doesn't work well with SPA's yet.

One roadblock I have found is that I am declaring an `ng-app="siteApp"` on a shared template to all pages (hence every page has this app).

On a given .html page for a component, I have a controller `ng-controller="RecipesCtrl"` and want to tie it into my app. I can't reference `siteApp` on this internal page, even though it exists in a global context: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=siteApp

If I include all the filters/controllers in the same .js file as `siteApp`, it works. If I put the controller on a different file that loads after siteApp, it can't find `siteApp`. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the CMS it's hard to put a finger on anything but try chunking things into modules and injecting them as dependencies in siteApp.

**Global JS file**

```
angular.module('siteApp', [
  'siteApp.recipes',
  'siteApp.ingredients',
  'siteApp.etc...'
]);
```

**Component's JS file**

```
angular.module('siteApp.recipes')
.controller('RecipesCtrl', [function () {

}]);
```

Comment: It's Adobe Experience Manager. I will give that approach a try.

Comment: I went with the approach outlined here, and it was successful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28233898/921310

Initializing an empty app module at the top of the page allowed me to implement controllers on a per-widget basis.